# Growth in a vector space

Tags: gr.group-theory, linear-algebra, finite-fields, additive-combinatorics, vector-spaces

I am interested in "growth" in finite vector spaces. I have been wondering about the veracity of the following statement:

> **Statement**: For every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $b\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ such that if $A$ is a subset of $V$, an $n$-dimensional vector space over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$, of size at least $|V|^{\varepsilon}$, then there exist linear transformations $T_1,\dots, T_b\in {\rm GL}(V)$ such that
>   $$T_1(A)+\cdots+ T_b(A)=V.$$

I am interested in knowing if this result is known and, if so, where I can find a reference. If it's not known, do you think it's true/ provable?

I'm guessing that it might be easier to prove such a result if one allows for some "smoothing" by taking sums or differences. If it helps to replace the displayed equation with, say,...
$$T_1(A-A)+\cdots+ T_b(A-A)=V$$
... then feel free -- I would still be interested in this...

Note that when $n=1$, we are just talking about covering a field by translates of a large subset of the field in which case [the result is known](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/167999/a-strong-sum-product-for-translates-in-finite-fields?rq=1).

My motivation, for what it's worth, comes from studying the Product Decomposition Conjecture of Liebeck--Nikolov--Shalev. This statement came up naturally as I was thinking about that conjecture... Thanks, in advance, for any thoughts that you may have...

Comment: Not quite what you want, but it is not difficult to find $b = O(\log \frac{1}{\epsilon \delta} ) $ and $T_1,\dots,T_b$ such that the sumset has cardinality at least $|V|^{1- \delta}$. In particular it is sufficient to consider a single $\epsilon$ in your question, e.g. $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Perhaps I'm being dense, but I now think that the general case follows easily from the $n=1$ case: simply impose an $\mathbb{F}_{q^n}$-field structure on $V$ and the multiplicative group then corresponds to a Singer cycle in ${\rm GL}(V)$... So the corresponding linear transformations do the job.